# WiFi dropping. Good Broadband

Tags: router, wireless-router

I have sky broadband router and on test always has a good signal with stable lights (3 green). WiFi may drop even though internet is good and this could be for a period of time, intermittently or occasionally. Usually laptops work well but WiFi calling and things like Skype seem to have poor stability. My wifi phone is 1 metre from the router without obstruction but sound often distorted.I'm in the UK and have previously had BT and Plusnet routers but they have been no different. Sky set up both 2.4 and 5 and put in a booster but this did not help.The house is not in a heavily built up area, is detached and of normal brick and tiled construction.
I would do almost anything to get a stable internet/wifi calling after years of problems. Would it be worth getting and extra phone line and another router from same/different provider?

Comment: In a business (even very small business) phone and internet/devices are often on separate lines. Update the firmware in your router to see if that helps. Make sure the router is a good one with high throughput.  On one problem device, make sure the OS is up to date and for a computer, try updating the wireless card driver.

Comment: Try @John's suggestions. Check Google maps, are you close to a local airport? Might also want to try something like wifi analyzer from the play store if you have an android, See what's up with your channels in the local environment.